# How to Connect rabbitMq server to the amazonmq

Tags: rabbitmq, amazon-eks, amazon-mq

I am new in this field and have not much experience so kindly help.
I have a AmazonMq instance whose machine is rabbitMq which is not publicly accessible. So i want to create a vhost in the AmazonMq broker. 
I need rabbitmqctl to create vhost in the rabbitmq so i install rabbitmq-server on my ec2 instance to connect it to my amazonmq instance but there is no rabbitmq.conf file where i can configure my host and port.

Answer (score 1):

what i did was have another publicly accessible EC2 in the same subnet as the AmazonMQ, installed nginx in it, turned off source/des check on Ec2, and placed this little file in the nginx.conf to configure it as reverse proxy,  and then i was able to access the dashboard from the Ec2's DNS name, if that's what you want, maybe then you can work with the dashboard even if it is not publicly accessible:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://rabbitmqbrokerURL.mq.region.amazonaws.com;
    }
```